# How to add Multiple JSON array Element depends on Example Data Set

Tags: karate

During my Karate scenario automation got the below problem statement. Could anyone please help me on this?

My JSON file will contain,

```
{
  "schema_id": 25,
  "records": [
    {
      "value": {
        "NUM_CHARGE_ID": "#(numChargeID)",
        "DTE_START": "2017-05-26",
        "NUM_DAY": "#(numDay)"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

From my Karate feature file I want to pass data from Example and depends on the data set it should create multiple array element in the json. Like,

```
Examples:
| numChargeID   | numDay|
|C10,C21,C15,C18|1,2,3,4|
```

```
{
  "schema_id": 25,
  "records": [
    {
      "value": {
        "NUM_CHARGE_ID": "C10",
        "DTE_START": "2017-05-26",
        "NUM_DAY": "1"
      },
      {
        "NUM_CHARGE_ID": "C21",
        "DTE_START": "2017-05-26",
        "NUM_DAY": "2"
      },
      {
        "NUM_CHARGE_ID": "C15",
        "DTE_START": "2017-05-26",
        "NUM_DAY": "3"
      },
      {
        "NUM_CHARGE_ID": "C18",
        "DTE_START": "2017-05-26",
        "NUM_DAY": "4"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way in Karate that i can handle this type of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to solve this and maybe you shouldn't try to force everything into `Examples:`. For instance:

```
* def chargeIds = ['C1', 'C2']
* def dayNums = [1, 2]
* def fun = function(x, i){ return { NUM_CHARGE_ID: x, NUM_DAY: dayNums[i] } }
* def records = karate.map(chargeIds, fun)
* print records
```

Which gives you:

```
[
  {
    "NUM_CHARGE_ID": "C1",
    "NUM_DAY": 1
  },
  {
    "NUM_CHARGE_ID": "C2",
    "NUM_DAY": 2
  }
]
```

What I would recommend is something like this:

```
* table records
| NUM_CHARGE_ID | NUM_DAY |
| 'C1'          | 1       |
| 'C2'          | 2       |

* print records
```

Which gives you the exact same thing.

Also look at the possible use of `set`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#set-multiple